# Rtesseract throws error after installing rtesseract gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tesseract

I need to user rtessract gem for my ruby on rails project for OCR. I have installed the gem rtesseract using

```
gem install rtesseract
```

but when i try to use that gem in my console it throws rtesseract not found error

Can any one have any solution for that. I have also placed the same in gem file and ran bundle but it doesnt work

Comment: How do you start the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RTesseract gem to work you need to install some dependencies like ImageMagick Leptonica and some gems like rmagick. you can install them using

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick leptonica
```

and rmagick gem using

```
gem install rmagick
```

or by placing the same in your gem file

You need to have tessdata folder in the

```
/usr/local/share/tessdata
```

if you dont have the tessdata you need to download tessdata from tesseract repositry and copy them to the above path

Comment: I have install all the dependencies earlier and now i have installed rmagick gem too but it throws the same error

Comment: Imagemagick inturn needs some dependencies to be installed have you installed them

Comment: I am using imagemagick from quite some time so there will be no issues from that

Comment: You need to have tessdata for the tesseract edited the answer regarding that please check it